# the max value of $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the max value of the term $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{b}$

If $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}=6$,

$a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$

I tried to get from the equation to the term but it's too complicated.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $w=\frac{a}{b}, x=\frac{b}{c}, y=\frac{c}{d}, z=\frac{d}{a}$, so that $wxyz=1, w+x+y+z=6$,  then $$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{d}{b}=wx+xy+yz+zw=(w+y)(x+z) \leq \frac{((w+y)+(x+z))^2}{4}=9$$

(Note $st \leq \frac{(s+t)^2}{4} \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq (s-t)^2$)

Equality is achieved when $w+y=x+z$, so $w+y=x+z=3, wxyz=1$. We can achieve this for example by $y=x=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}, w=z=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, $(a, b, c, d)=(1, \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}, 1, \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2})$.

Comment: $4st\leq s^2 + t^2$ is false.

Comment: @pppqqq Sorry a typo. Should have been $4st \leq (s+t)^2$, which was what I used. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @IvanLoh - why did you think about $\frac{(s+t)^2}{4}$? why this term? it seems to me out of the blue.

Comment: @ash Well, we want to find the maximum value of $st$, where $s=w+y$ and $t=x+z$. We know $s+t=6$. So, (having seen many similar problems) it was sort of natural to consider $st \leq \frac{(s+t)^2}{4}$. Of course, equality may not necessarily hold, so we still have to check that the value is indeed achievable.